# how do i set a condition on an onSubmit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, use-state

im working with a form and i want every first onSubmit to pop up an error message, and then work normally the second time around and so forth. heres what i have

```
const [submitting, setSubmitting] = useState(false);

const handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setSubmitting(true);
    
    setTimeout(() => {
      setSubmitting(false);
    }, 1000);
  }
```

and heres the error message i wanna inject for every first onSubmit

```
    setSubmitting(false);
  }, 2000);

  alert("An error has occured");
```

i want to be able to define whether or not my error message has already been shown, but after the first submit, my form forgets that the error message has already been shown. How should i go about solving  this?

Answer (score 0):

Just track it in your state:

```
const [errorHasShown, setErrorHasShown] = useState(false);

if (!errorHasShown) {
    setErrorHasShown(true);
    alert("An error has occured");
}
```

Comment: do I put this inside or outside my handleSubmit function? I tried putting it inside but it would still submit while also having the error message. I also put an else statement  for the default but would never actually get to the else statement and would just keep getting an error message